# read and write Infinite about of names into text file

Tags: python-3.x

Here's as far as I got http://pastebin.com/mfJfp5sB I'm only able to store up to one name at a  time. I'm wondering how I would be able to create a dictionary of all names entered and check if the person's name has been entered before.

```
    blue = "\033[94m"

name = input("What's your name?")

with open("name.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for part in line.split():
            if name in part:
                    print(blue + "I remember you " + name + "!")
            else:
                print("Well Nice to meet you " + name + "!")

file = open("name.txt", "w")
file.write(name)
file.close()
```

Comment: You need to look into the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) modes, `'w'` means to truncate (i.e. zero out the file) - perhaps you meant `'w+'`

Comment: @Aprexo, if you fixed the problem please also write the solution to the answer.

Comment: Try using `'w+'` or `'a'` instead of `'w'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if helps tell me:

```
name = input("What's your name?")
with open("name.txt", 'a') as openfile:
     openfile.write(name)
with open("name.txt",'r+') as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for part in line.split():
            if name in part:
                    print(blue + "I remember you " + name + "!")
            else:
                print("Well Nice to meet you " + name + "!")
```